# How do I create two new variables for how many days between the most recent game played by each team?

Tags: r

I would like to create two new variables (one for team1, another for team2). Each variable should tell me how many days between the most recent game played by each team.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

date <- c(mdy("May 7, 2021", "May 7, 2021", "May 6, 2021", "May 5, 2021", "May 5, 2021"))
team1 <- c("Boston Celtics", "Orlando Magic", "Atlanta Hawks", "Boston Celtics", "Phoenix Suns")
team2 <- c("Chicago Bulls", "Charlotte Hornets", "Indiana Pacers", "Orlando Magic", "Atlanta Hawks")
games <- data.frame(date, team1, team2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this provides the output you are interested in.

In this answer, you can first assign each row of data to a unique `Game` number. Then, put data into long form, and calculate days between games for each team. Finally, if desired, you can put data into wide format again.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

games %>%
  mutate(Game = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("team"), 
               values_to = "Team", 
               names_to = "Number", 
               names_pattern = "team(\\d+)") %>%
  group_by(Team) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(Days_Between = c(0, diff(date))) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Game, date), 
              names_from = Number, 
              values_from = c(Team, Days_Between))
```

**Output**

```
   Game date       Team_1         Team_2            Days_Between_1 Days_Between_2
  <int> <date>     <chr>          <chr>                      <dbl>          <dbl>
1     4 2021-05-05 Boston Celtics Orlando Magic                  0              0
2     5 2021-05-05 Phoenix Suns   Atlanta Hawks                  0              0
3     3 2021-05-06 Atlanta Hawks  Indiana Pacers                 1              0
4     1 2021-05-07 Boston Celtics Chicago Bulls                  2              0
5     2 2021-05-07 Orlando Magic  Charlotte Hornets              2              0
```